# Unable to run shoutem v5 code using react-native run-ios

Tags: shoutem

After doing a "shoutem pull-app", I tried running the react native code on my simulator using "react-native run-ios".  I am getting this error:

> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShoutemApp.app An error was encountered processing the command
>   (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2): Failed to install the requested
>   application An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
>   Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle. Print: Entry,
>   ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>
> Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShoutemApp.app/Info.plist
>   Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Answer (score 1):

The `shoutem pull-app` command is used to get all the code in the same place. If you want to change an extension, go to extension directory (e.g. `shoutem-news`) inside of `extensions` directory and push it as your own extension. Now you can see the changes locally by doing `shoutem run`, `shoutem run-ios` or `shoutem run-android`.

It's on our roadmap to support doing `react-native run-ios` / `react-native run-android` from the downloaded repository.

Comment: Are you saying it's not possible right now? When do you plan on implementing that feature?

Comment: Commands `shoutem run-ios` and `shoutem run-android` internally call `react-native run-ios` and `react-native run-android` so that already works. The only difference is that they also fetch the app configuration from the server.

Comment: So can we make changes to the extension while we have our app running?  Can we make changes to both the app and server directories of the extension?

Comment: Yes. Just do `shoutem link` to link your extension to app and then you will be able to change the code and reload the app to immediately view the changes. You can see here for more details: http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/setting-local-environment